# Scheme for Weighted Voting on Ensemble Machine Learning System

Tags: machine-learning, classification, voting-system

I'm designing a machine learning system in which i'm training 4 different classifiers and voting among it's predictions to decide on an output. Presently i'm just making a simple vote (i.e. selecting the most recurring predicted class) but can't I do something better using the outputted probabilities of the models as a sort of weight to decide on the best class?

Answer (score 2):

> can't I do something better using the outputted probabilities of the models as a sort of weight to decide on the best class?

Yes, see [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) for ideas. E.g. stacking sometimes outperforms the majority vote scheme.